# Renumbering the records in Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table t with following values in `col1` -

```
1
1
3
4
4
4
5
7
10
13
```

I need to renumber it as following, so it will erase the gaps between numbers.

```
1
1
2
3
3
3
4
5
6
7
```

I am able to find the gap ranges. Didn't find the way to renumber - tried to apply analytical function with `row_num()` but cannot get correct result. Code should work in both Oracle and SQL Server, so `connect by` level is probably not the best way.

Comment: why not use a stored procedure or java/php code to do it?

Comment: It was a request for sql, not the procedure or java code... Great help @Tim-Schmelter - it is dense_rank and works in Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That look like a `DENSE_RANK`, SQL-Server:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Col1, RANK = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 ASC)
    FROM dbo.Table1
)
UPDATE CTE SET Col1 = RANK 
WHERE Col1 <> RANK
```

I'm not familiar with Oracle (anymore) but there's also a [`Dense_Rank`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm) function.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9c98/3/0)</kbd>

```
COL1
1
1
2
3
3
3
4
5
6
7
```